# How to use Global.asax file to redirect the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What should be done if I want to redirect a user based on their ISO Codes?

And how should I detect a website user's IS Code in the first place? Like I know there are these server variables that we use to detect Client IP and all (HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR, REMOTE_ADDRESS, etc) but information 
about them on the many sites that I have read has got me confused about what to use. Like some say there can be comma separated IPs returned by HTTP_FORWARDED_X and out of those IPs , one is not sure which is the real IP and which are the proxy addresses. Also, that all the IP addresses in returned can be fake.

So my questions are:-

1. How to I fetch the REAL IP Address of a person? Like I only want to know what country a particular person is sitting so I can redirect the user accordingly.
2. Secondly lets say a person is sitting in US then I want the user to be redirected to www.mysite.us.
   If a person is visiting my site from Germany, www.mysite.de is the address that I want the person to be redirected to.
3. Also if DE is the ISO Code then I want my GermanMaster.master page to load and if its US then I want that the USMaster.master should load.

So how do I fetch a user's not fake IP address, redirect a user based on that ISO code and then load a master page according to the ISO Code.

How do I go about it? I haven't ever worked with Global.asax before so clueless how to go about it all. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about the IP address location services, but if you want to dynamically load a specific MasterPage based on some criteria, then you'll want to use the `Page_PreInit` event in the page's life cycle.

Of course, the page needs to be a Content page, with a reference to a MasterPage in the `@Page` directive.  It doesn't matter which MasterPage you use in the `@Page` directive, just as long as it's there to indicate that the page is a Content page.  In the code behind (or in a base class), something like the following would work:

C#

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

VB

```
Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    Me.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master"
End Sub
```

You would just put whatever logic you want in this method to pick the correct MasterPage.  The key is that you have to make the change in the `PreInit` event.  Changing the MasterPage after that event is not allowed and ASP.NET will throw a nasty error.

As an extension to this, I've implemented a technique that utilizes the `Session_Start` method to execute the logic to determine the current MasterPage, placing the name of the file into the `Session`.  The `PreInit` method would then simply load the MasterPage file name from the `Session` rather than having to think about which one to use.  (It's probably better to use `String.Format`, but for this example I'm just concatenating the values.)  You might also want to verify that `Session("MasterPage")` actually has a value (and perhaps even a *valid* value) before changing the `MasterPageFile` property.  Things can get a bit ugly if you change it to a file that doesn't exist.

C#

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/" + Session("MasterPage") + ".master";
}
```

VB

```
Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    Me.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/" & Session("MasterPage") & ".master"
End Sub
```

You might find some useful information on this page, [Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), which is where I grabbed the first code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Check this for determining locale: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/334.aspx

Then in global.asax, if you want to check this when the user's session starts, then use Session_Start, there's also BeginRequest event of the application (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx).  I don't know if BeginRequest is too soon for the handler, we do some checks in AcquireRequestState (which fires once session is established).  That depends on whether you want to run the code on the first time the app runs, or every time the pages postback.

Also, you could build this into the framework; create your own custom page class which does the check on every page load or the first time the page runs.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Globalization and Localization, MSDN has some good resources online [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx). To get the users Geo data from the IP address there are several services, I have the [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/) static data and Webservices and had no problems.